# Imagemagick, Snow Leopard and PDF Conversion

Tags: macos, pdf, osx-snow-leopard, imagemagick, ghostscript

Having difficulties with Imagemagick and Snow Leopard.

Imagemagick was installed using the install script from here [here](http://github.com/maddox/magick-installer/tree).  Everything builds and installs correctly.  Imagemagick behave normally for all commands (that I can find) except when trying to convert a PDF.  For example,

```
$ convert my.pdf my.jpg
Segmetation Fault
```

I thought it may be ghostscript and tried to run the command that Imagegick delegates too (via the -verbose option)

```
$ convert -verbose spec/fixtures/documents/upload_test_file.pdf test.jpg
"gs" -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=/var/folders/Xz/Xz6TDr0DFQaV5J1F7Ndamk+++TM/-Tmp-/magick-4zvJXfSz" "-f/var/folders/Xz/Xz6TDr0DFQaV5J1F7Ndamk+++TM/-Tmp-/magick-O7a9fDyp" "-f/var/folders/Xz/Xz6TDr0DFQaV5J1F7Ndamk+++TM/-Tmp-/magick-rBEzLUsx"
Segmentation fault
$ "gs" -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=my.jpg" "-fmy.pdf"
```

And it works.  It creates the pnmrow file as its supposed to.

I am not sure where to go from here, anyone else seen this or seen it and solved it?

Comment: Seems like a SuperUser question...

Comment: that's a good point, is there an easy way to move it over?

Comment: If not it would be a pretty cool feature to be able to vote for a question to be moved between the stackoverflow and serverfault sites.

Comment: my bad, I cross posted it and didn't close this one. Here it is http://superuser.com/questions/35995/imagemagick-snow-leopard-and-pdf-conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me too.

```
$ identify issue7.pdf 
Segmentation fault
```

Looks like the imagemagick team is [aware of the problem](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14606&sid=a8f08cc293f10c22fd54a2b4e08c03da) and it should be fixed in version 6.5.5-8.

UPDATE: Actually - The MacPorts package uses the newer version of ImageMagick as of 9/16/09.  Try doing a self update and then upgrading php5-imagick.

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade php5-imagick
```

This fixed the problem for me.